# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Кэт невольно засматривается на это самое небо, и, наконец, понимает, что больше не чувствует нервной дрожи.

Comment: Какие знаки вызывают сомнение?